# Setting wal_level on in docker postgres conf file

Tags: postgresql, docker, debezium

In order to use Debezium I need to set `wal_level` to `logical` in my Postgres server. Postgres is running in container. So I edited `postgresql.conf` file located in `var/lib/postgresql/data/` in Docker Desktop application. I restarted the container, moved over to pgAdmin web interface, refreshed my PostgresServer (in left pane right click -> Refresh...). But if I check it using `SHOW wal_level;` it still say `replica`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured a volume for this directory. Otherwise when you restart the container the changes to postgresql.conf will be lost and then it  will start again with default variables.

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed, the `$PGDATA` directory does not get persisted unless you manually mount a volume when starting up the container.  If you do this, then your change to `wal_level` will get persisted.

If you do not wish to have a separate volume, you can use initialization scripts [as mentioned in the image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).  To do this, you can do the following:

1. Create a directory to hold your scripts
2. Create a Bash script to instruct the container to set the `wal_level`
3. Set `+x` to the script so it can run
4. Start the container with a mapping from your directory to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Example below:

```
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  staff   96 Oct 13 09:51 .
drwx------@ 10 user  staff  320 Oct 13 09:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  staff   96 Oct 13 09:58 ext

$ cat ext/init.sh 
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level to logical;
EOSQL

$ docker run -v ./ext/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

...
2023-10-13 17:03:40 UTC
2023-10-13 17:03:40.939 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
ALTER SYSTEM

...
2023-10-13 17:03:41.209 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Then:

```
$ docker exec -it <container_name> psql -c "SHOW wal_level" postgres postgres
 wal_level 
-----------
 logical
(1 row)
```